# Django-image-cropping is not working outside admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I wish to use django-image-cropping outside the django admin interface. Inside it is working. Also I can get the example of django-image-cropping to work. But it is just not showing the right widgets. Why?

#### Excerpt of my models.py:

```python
# ...
class Person(TranslatableModel):
    # ...
    pic = ImageCropField(_("profile picture"),
                         blank=True,
                         null=True,
                         upload_to=settings.USER_PICTURE_DIR,
                         )
    picture_cropped = ImageRatioField(
        'pic',
        '{}x{}'.format(*settings.USER_PICTURE_SIZE)
    )
    # ...
```

#### Excerpt of my forms.py:

```python
# ...
class PersonUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            'pic',
            'picture_cropped',
        ]
```

#### Excerpt of my views.py:

```python
# ...
class PersonUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, OnlySelfMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'persons/person_intern_form.html'
    form_class = PersonUpdateForm
    # ...
```

#### Excerpt of my person_intern_form.html:

```html
{% extends 'intern/intern_base.html' %}
{% load i18n sekizai_tags %}

{% block main_content %}
    <form action="{{ action }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
{% endblock main_content %}

{% addtoblock "css" %}
    {{ form.media.css }}
{% endaddtoblock %}

{% addtoblock "js" %}
    {{ form.media.js }}
{% endaddtoblock %}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. sekizai_tags require to be in a block: [django-sekizai](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#restrictions)
2. jquery has not been loaded correctly. (Not visible in the code)

Comment: Hey, I'm currently having the same problem, what did you change in your code in order to fix it?

Comment: Sure. 

In settings.py: IMAGE_CROPPING_JQUERY_URL = 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' (Telling image cropping to use jquery of the admin interface)

Then open the developer tools of your browser and check if loading of jquery works (check for 404 in the network tab).